# QT Quick C++ Application with multiple screens

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I am new to QT Quick and QML and I am trying to build a Linux Desktop multi screen application using C++ and QT. I have seen the examples provided by QT but most of the examples are single screen and not explaining how to have multiple screens and how the screen stack is maintained and how screens communicate with each other and what are the ways available.

An example for multi screen QT Quick C++ application will help.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example:

**main.cpp**

interesting part of `main` function:

```
QObject *QMLmainWindow = engine.rootObjects()[0];
QQuickWindow *QMLsecondWindow = QMLmainWindow->findChild<QQuickWindow*>("secondWindow");

QQmlComponent *qml = new QQmlComponent(&engine, QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/ThirdWindow.qml")));
QQuickWindow *QMLthirdWindow = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(qml->create());

QList<QScreen*> screens = app.screens();

if (screens.count() > 1) {
    QRect secScreenGeometry = screens.at(1)->geometry();
    QMLsecondWindow->setProperty("visible", true);
    QMLsecondWindow->setX(secScreenGeometry.x());
    QMLsecondWindow->setY(secScreenGeometry.y());
    QMLsecondWindow->resize(secScreenGeometry.width(), secScreenGeometry.height());

    QMLthirdWindow->setScreen(screens.at(1));
    QMLthirdWindow->setProperty("visible", true);
}

return app.exec();
```

and QML files with definitions of windows:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    SecondWindow {
        id: secondWindow
        objectName: "secondWindow"
    }
}
```

**SecondWindow.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: false
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Second Window")
}
```

**ThirdWindow.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: false
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Third Window")
}
```

**QQuickWindow** has an inherited method `setScreen`, but this method works only for top level windows. As you can see, `QMLthirdWindow` is created as indpendent window and we're allowed to use `setScreen` method.

But if we want to move `QMLsecondWindow`, we need to do this "manually". So we need to read geometry of proper screen and set X, Y parameters of window for those placed on destination screen. In the result of above example "Main Window" will be displayed centered at main screen (0), "Second Window" will be displayed at second screen (1) with maximum size, and "Third Window" will be displayed centered at second screen (1).

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sample. But I was thinking of C++ Class for every QML screen which will have all the control and communication with the QML screen. And there will be some central place which will maintain the screen stack exposing APIs to push or pop the screen from the screen stack. How this can be implemented.

Comment: Is it that the code `QObject *QMLmainWindow = engine.rootObjects()[0];
QQuickWindow *QMLsecondWindow = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(QMLmainWindow->findChild<QObject*>("secondWindow"));` Will go in in a separate class called ClassSecondWindow. Also what is `QList<QScreen*> screens = app.screens();` is doing?

Comment: Ok, you didn't mention this detail about screen manager class in your question so i wrote basic example :) now you see how its going so you can wrap what you need into some core screen management class. If you pass somehow to your class pointer to engine variable, you can "catch" qml windows like that wherever you want. QList screens is only shortcut to not use `app.screens()`-you can ignore this and use `app.screens()` wherever you want access to list of screens. And `app` is ofcourse QGuiApplication object which is created by default in Qt Quick Application at the beginning of main function.

Comment: Yes I am looking for the same example for multiple screen/windows will it possible to point to some sample code?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know any example of such class. For my purposes standard methods from Qt (like in example) is enough so I can't help more for now. But I'm sure you can do this for your own! Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am getting error for the line `screens.at(1)->geometry();` when I try to build your code using QT Creator.

Comment: add #include <QScreen>

Comment: Ok, but I am not very sure what is the code in main function is doing. The screen.count() is always 1 and I do not see SecondWindow when I start the application. I have added some Text in the screens. But I see only main screen when I run this application.

Comment: We have a little misunderstand, I think. This example show how to display application windows on multiple screens (monitors). Now I'm guessing you are asking for application that use multiple windows at one screen? If yes, foreget about QScreen and ask another, more precise question... Screens are not the same as windows.

Comment: Oh sorry for this confusion I am looking for multiple screens or windows or pages based application and how these multiple things can communicate with each other and I am not able to find this example

Comment: Qt Quick Layouts is thing you are looking for in this case. See what you can get about them by yourself and eventually ask about layouts :)

Answer (score 0):

Since we have [Qt.application.screens](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#application-prop) I would use pure QML for that, for example:

```
Item {
    id: root
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: {
        for(var i = 0;i < Qt.application.screens.length;i ++)
        {
            wnd.createObject(root, {wndIndex: i});
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: wnd
        Window {
            property int wndIndex: 0
            visible: true
            width: 640
            height: 480
            title: qsTr("Screen " + wndIndex)
            screen: Qt.application.screens[wndIndex]
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing in this case that we need to use `QQuickView` instead of `QQmlApplicationEngine`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
    view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view->show();    
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: tested on Qt6.4, does not work, no error and no window shows up. detect two Qt.application.screens.